# User cannot trigger endpoint of a Google Cloud Function

Tags: ssl, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I have a Google Cloud Function, with a specific HTTP trigger. Let's say : `https://europe-west1-test-planner-1677944.cloudfunctions.net/test_connector`

When a user send a request to the dedicated endpoint:

- There is no logs associated. The function wasn't called.
- He receive this error : Unable to open TCP/IP port of the server : `europe-west1-test-planner-1677944.cloudfunctions.net/test_connector:443`

What does that mean ? How can I fix this ? Should I somehow open port 443 through GCP Firewall ? I thought all this was managed by Google.

Comment: Without knowing exactly how the request is being sent, there's not much we can do to help.  Please edit your question to provide enough information that anyone can use to duplicate the scenario and observe the result as you see it.

Answer (score 0):

Your question lacks detail:

- Can other users make the request successfully?
  If so, what's different?
- How is the user making the request?
  Browser?
  Some other client?
- Can the user access other sites e.g. google.com?

Assuming (!) that other users are able to access the Cloud Function and that, if the endpoint requires authentication|authorization, the user is applying these correctly, it would be useful to determine whether this user can access anything else.

1. Can they browse http://www.google.com?
   If not, then the issue is with their Internet access.
2. If they're using a web browser to access the Cloud Function
   Does a different browser work?
   if they have access to a tool like `curl`, can they `curl` the endpoint (`curl https://europe-west1-test-planner-1677944.cloudfunctions.net/test_connector`)